# DRF exception 'NotAuthenticated' raising 500 Internal Server Error in place of 401/403

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, http-error, django-middleware

I have a Django middleware where I verify a firebase IDToken.

```
from rest_framework import exceptions

def process_request(request):
    ...
    try:
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
        uid = decoded_token['uid']
    except:
        raise exceptions.NotAuthenticated(detail='not authenticated')
```

When the verification fails, auth raises an exception, which is caught by the try except block. But instead of raising 401/403 error, 500 Internal Server Error is raised by NotAuthenticated.

Is it because of some working of DRF Exceptions that this is happening ?

Comment: make sure the response the raise is sending is in json format. could you share the exact error message that's displayed in the console logs,

Comment: exceptions.NotAuthenticated(detail='not authenticated') will create a string object instead you need a json object, try using detail={"error": "not authenticated"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DRF handles sending status code 401 or 403](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.12.4/rest_framework/views.py#L71) depending on the exception that got raised (`NotAuthenticated`, `PermissionDenied`) from your **view**.

But since you are working with a middleware, DRF is already out of the picture. Any exceptions that you raise which are not caught or handled by default will be considered as a server error, hence giving you a `500`.

If you want your middleware to return a 401 or 403, you can use django's `HttpResponse` or `HttpResponseForbidden` like so:

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse, HttpResponseForbidden

class MyMiddlware:
    def process_request(request):
        try:
            decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
            uid = decoded_token['uid']
        except Exception:
            return HttpResponseForbidden('not authenticated')
       # or return HttpResponse('not authenticated', status=401)
```